# Is there a solution manual for Royden fourth edition?

Tags: measure-theory, reference-request, lebesgue-integral

I bought the fourth edition of Royden Real Analysis, this book is awesome and it's quite different from the third edition, which has less exercises.

I have the solution manual for the third edition. Is there a solution manual for the fourth edition?

I always like doing the exercises by myself, but it is very important for me to be able to verify that they are correctly solved.

Comment: Did you purchase a third edition or did you just hunt one down online? If so, it would be appreciated - I have studied from that text, but I have been unable to find a solutions manual myself.

Comment: The fourth edition is not by Royden, it is by Royden and Fitzpatrick.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This book is such a gem! As a hobby, I've been writing up solutions to the exercises in my free time. You can download them from [my website](https://sites.google.com/view/djtmalison/personal?authuser=0). I've only managed to make it through Chapter 8 though.

I hope you find these useful - my only request is to please let me know if you find any errors :-)

Comment: thank you very much, it is not going to be useful for me after that many years, but surely someone will find very useful your answer :)

Comment: I’m not sure this is a mistake but maybe something I would like more info about. In section 2.3 problem 15 on page 38 you use countable additivity but this property is not proven until section 2.5. I don’t think your proof is wrong, but I’m inclined to think that there is an alternative that only uses countable sub-additivity.

Comment: @ToucanIan Thanks for the feedback! I updated the solution to that exercise.

Comment: In section 2.4 problem 18 you appear to make the assumption that E is measurable. In my version of the text E is simply stated to have a finite measure but is not said to be measurable.

Comment: Yeah I agree the language a little ambiguous. I believe "finite measure" implies the set is measurable, in contrast with the term "finite outer measure" (e.g. exercise 14). It doesn't make much sense to say a set's measure is finite if the set is not measurable.

Comment: My version of the text explicitly says “finite outer measure” I did not correctly relay this in the original comment. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solutions manual through Section 14.4 of the 2018 reissue of the fourth edition: [https://www.amazon.com/dp/B09ZCYSB8Z](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B09ZCYSB8Z).